# Prevent getText() evaluating EL expressions

Tags: java, regex, jsp, struts2, ognl

In Struts2 backend, I have an action class instance variable, eg: `keyName`. A dynamic key returned to view(JSP).

This `keyName` variable is set using a request parameter using POST method. Depending on the request parameter value, the `keyName` will vary.

In JSP, I am using `<s:property value="getText(keyName)" />` to show the label corresponding to the key given by keyName variable.

When I send an EL expression for example `${90-40}` to `keyName` this expression is being evaluated and resulting in showing 50 on the UI.

How can we avoid or prevent such EL injection with `getText()`?

Is there any other alternative way instead of `<s:property value="getText(keyName)" />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own text provider and register it in `struts.xml`:

```xml
<constant name="struts.xworkTextProvider" value="com.struts.text.MyTextProvier"/>
```

Now create a class `MyTextProvier` that extends `TextProviderSupport` and override `getText()` methods. All methods take a parameter `key` as `String` and you can replace unwanted characters from it. Then call `super.getText()`. For example

```java
public String getText(String key) {
  return super.getText(key.replaceAll("[\\$\\{\\}]", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<s:text name="keyName" />`

http://struts.apache.org/docs/text.html

Comment: The link is broken.